# LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol NtProcessStartup

Tags: c, windows, minifilter, wdm

I am new to Windows driver development and minifilters and I am trying to build the [nullFilter](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/nullFilter) sample using command line tools.
So I added `#pragma comment(lib, "FltMgr.lib")` to the .c file and issued the following commands successfully:

```
cl.exe /nologo /Fo../../bin\filter.obj /c filter.c /D _AMD64_
rc.exe /nologo /Fo../../bin\filter.res filter.rc
```

However, when I try to create the sys file:

```
link.exe /nologo /DRIVER:WDM /out:../../bin\filter.sys ../../bin\filter.obj ../../bin\filter.res
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol NtProcessStartup
../../bin\filter.sys : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I am using VS2012 Express and WDM8. My LIB environment variable is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\km\x64;
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NtProcessStartup function is to driver development what 'main' is for regular C programs. In other words, it is the program entry function that you need to provide yourself. See the article [here](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/writing-windows-kernel-mode-driver/) for an introduction and explanation of this function. You can overrule the name of the startup function by using the -entry linker option. Setting '-entry:DriverEntry' is a common practice for driver development.

Comment: Hi. I am facing a similar problem as above. My problem is explained in detail in the below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584201/winrt-library-not-working-in-release-mode

As per your advice, I tried adding the /entry:DriverEntry in my project's Linker menu. But now I am getting an error as error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DriverEntry
Can you tell me where I am going wrong.?

Comment: See my answer to the question in the link you gave. You're not supposed to get a NtProcessStartup error for non-device driver applications.